# Postgresql text search between two strings

Tags: string, postgresql, search

I am looking to search in a string column (say, 'fruit') for all items between two string values.

example items in the column:

```
apple
berry
blueberry
cherry
pear
```

For example, I would like to search for all values between 'apple' and 'cherry'

It might look something this.

`SELECT fruit_name FROM fruit WHERE fruit_name >= 'apple' and fruit_name <= 'cherry'`

which should return:

```
apple
berry
blueberry
cherry
```

(not pear)

Not sure how to do this, since:

`fruit_name ilike 'apple%'` only returns words that begin with 'apple'

and

`SELECT fruit_name FROM fruit WHERE fruit_name BETWEEN 'apple' and 'cherry'`

doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Sorry, I believe the problem was with my search criteria and not my syntax.

Comment: SELECT fruit_name FROM fruit WHERE fruit_name >= 'apple' and fruit_name <= 'cherry' does work.